# Why are momentum balance equations formulated in terms of net stress rather than net force?

Tags: solid-mechanics

In engineering, a steady state equilibrium force balance is typically expressed as  $$\nabla\cdot \sigma=0$$ where $\sigma$ is the stress (force per unit area) applied at a point.  It seems more intuitive to me to express the force balance as $$\sum F = 0$$.  What does the first equation capture that the second equation doesn't?  That is, what advantages does $\nabla\cdot \sigma=0$ have over $\sum F = 0$ to represent this steady state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stress tensor may be continuous rather than due to a discrete number of forces e.g. in fluid mechanics. For example the [Cauchy momentum equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_momentum_equation) is naturally written using the divergence of the stress tensor.

Answer (score 0):

The divergence form of the equilibrium equation is obtained by summing the forces over a small cube that has the same area on opposite faces.   So, in effect, they both represent force equilibrium.   General principle:  equilibrium applies to forces, not stresses.